# scala 2.13 : unable to load a Suite class that was discovered in the runpath Cause: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json4s/JsonAST$JValue

Tags: scala, unit-testing, dependencies, scala-2.13

I am migrating a project from scala 2.12 to 2.13 and I manage to make everything to compile. Buy when I run my tests I get an error

```
com.alexm.spark.ml.bojo.StringValueImputerTest *** ABORTED ***
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load a Suite class that was discovered in the runpath: com.alexm.spark.ml.bojo.StringValueImputerTest
  at org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite$.getSuiteInstance(DiscoverySuite.scala:81)
  at org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite.$anonfun$nestedSuites$1(DiscoverySuite.scala:38)
  at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:100)
  at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:87)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Vector.map(Vector.scala:113)
  at org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite.<init>(DiscoverySuite.scala:37)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.genDiscoSuites$1(Runner.scala:1168)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1253)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:1033)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:1011)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json4s/JsonAST$JValue
  at org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.JobsTab.<init>(JobsTab.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:484)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2704)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:953)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:202)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:947)
  at com.alexm.spark.WithSpark$.getSpark(WithSpark.scala:116)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json4s.JsonAST$JValue
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.JobsTab.<init>(JobsTab.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:484)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2704)
  ...
*** RUN ABORTED ***
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json4s/JsonAST$JValue
  at org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.JobsTab.<init>(JobsTab.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:484)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2704)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:953)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:202)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:947)
  at com.alexm.spark.WithSpark$.getSpark(WithSpark.scala:116)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json4s.JsonAST$JValue
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.JobsTab.<init>(JobsTab.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:484)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2704)
  ...
```

my pom file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>2.11</id>
            <properties>
                <scala.major>2.11</scala.major>
                <scala.minor>8</scala.minor>
                <scala.version>${scala.major}.${scala.minor}</scala.version>
                <spark.version>2.3.1</spark.version>
                <atl.version>0.2.4</atl.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>2.12</id>
            <properties>
                <scala.major>2.12</scala.major>
                <scala.minor>10</scala.minor>
                <scala.version>${scala.major}.${scala.minor}</scala.version>
                <spark.version>3.0.0</spark.version>
                <atl.version>0.2.4</atl.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>2.13</id>
            <properties>
                <scala.major>2.13</scala.major>
                <scala.minor>8</scala.minor>
                <scala.version>${scala.major}.${scala.minor}</scala.version>
                <spark.version>3.3.0</spark.version>
                <atl.version>1.0.4</atl.version>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.testSource>1.8</maven.compiler.testSource>
        <maven.compiler.testTarget>1.8</maven.compiler.testTarget>
        <jersey.version>2.22.2</jersey.version>
        <jar_path>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${project.build.finalName}</jar_path>

        <!--this property is needed by javax.ws.rs-api 2.1-->
        <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>

        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.alexm.spark.ml</groupId>
    <artifactId>featureTransformations_${scala.major}_${spark.version}</artifactId>
    <version>1.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Spark application</description>

    <organization>
        <name>Model Building</name>
        <url>https://office.alexm.com/staff/team.html?orgunit_id=60004272</url>
    </organization>


    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven-alexm-snapshots</id>
            <name>alexm Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://jfrog.alexm.com:443/artifactory/maven-alexm-snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-alexm-releases</id>
            <name>alexm Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://jfrog.alexm.com/artifactory/maven-alexm-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@gitlab.alexm.com:core/feature-engineering/model-building/feature-transformations.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>featureTransformations-1.2</tag>
    </scm>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.major}</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alexm.atl</groupId>
            <artifactId>atl_${scala.major}</artifactId>
            <version>${atl.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json4s-jackson_${scala.major}</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.major}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.major}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.major}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.major}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>nodeps</classifier>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>false</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                    <preparationGoals>clean test</preparationGoals>
                    <scmCommentPrefix>[maven-release-plugin][ci skip]</scmCommentPrefix>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-parent-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
                <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                    <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaCompatVersion>${scala.major}</scalaCompatVersion>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

Can you explain this kind of problems? How can a class be found at the runpath but not be loaded. Does it mean that it is not at the classpath? Do I miss something from my pom?

Comment: Not sure what is exactly your question here. You want to solve the error you got or you want to understand what's is causing that error? in case of the first one, you have en exclusion for `json4s` importing the `atl` dependency, but not sure if that is exactly the problem. please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For the second case, the article [runtime vs compile time](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/runtime-vs-compile-time) and [ClassNotFoundException vs NoClassDefFoundError](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classnotfoundexception-and-noclassdeffounderror) might help you to undestand what is happening.

Comment: The stacktrace show that the problem is when the program called to [java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#findClass(java.lang.String)). It says that in can throw `ClassNotFoundException - if the class could not be found, or if the loader is closed.`